# Parsing and Ignore Null Data Inside Multidimensional Array on Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array, that shown from print_r(json_encode($test)); in my controller just like this:

```
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"},{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}]]
```

And my code :

```
public function getUserAchievement(){
    $test = array();
    $res = array();
    $data = $this->queries_trend->getDataCustomer();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($test, $this->passing($value['Customer'], $value['Project']));
    }
    print_r(json_encode($test));
}

public function passing($customer, $project){
    $date = DATE("Y-m-d");
    $time = DATE("H:i:s");
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT t_closed_by As Username, ixt_user_type.user_owner As Role,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 day THEN 1 END ) as today,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 7 day THEN 1 END ) as weekly,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 month THEN 1 END ) as monthly,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 year THEN 1 END ) as yearly
                FROM p_".$customer."_".$project."_ticket
                LEFT JOIN m_event_type ON p_".$customer."_".$project."_ticket.t_req_type = m_event_type.ev_type
                LEFT JOIN ixt_user_type ON m_event_type.ev_user_type_target = ixt_user_type.user_type
                WHERE t_status = 9
                GROUP BY t_closed_by; ")->result_array();
     return $query;
}
```

My question is, how to filter data if there is condition null array in multidimensional array and convert into like this :

```
[[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"}],[{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}]]
```

Need Help, Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `array_filter($array)` to remove all the elements/inner arrays which are null.
2. Use `rest($array)` to return the first `array(suitable in your case)`.
3. Use `json_encode($array)` to return the data in json format.

   ```
   $filtered_array = array_filter($test);
   print_r(json_encode(reset($filtered_array)));
   ```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I still dont get it man @ZEN-Oh-sama , can you combine with my code ?

Comment: it return false

Comment: `public function getUserAchievement(){
    $test = array();
    $res = array();
    $data = $this->queries_trend->getDataCustomer();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($test, $this->passing($value['Customer'], $value['Project']));
    }
    $filtered_array = array_filter($test);
    print_r(json_encode(reset($filtered_array)));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$array = '[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"},{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}]]';

$array = json_decode($array);

$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $a){
    if ($a) {
        array_push($newArray, $a);
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

In your case, update function getUserAchievement() to :

```
public function getUserAchievement(){
    $test = array();
    $res = array();
    $data = $this->queries_trend->getDataCustomer();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($test, $this->passing($value['Customer'], $value['Project']));
    }

    // print_r(json_encode($test));

    $newArray = [];
    foreach($test as $t){
        if ($t) {
            array_push($newArray, $t);
        }
    }
    var_dump($newArray);
}
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @anggriyulio, it doesnt work, the format value still wrong man

Answer (score 0):

**try this, i made a few line of changes**

```
public function getUserAchievement(){
    $test = array();
    $res = array();
    $data = $this->queries_trend->getDataCustomer();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $resultPassing = $this->passing($value['Customer'], $value['Project']);
        echo'<pre>';print_r($resultPassing);
        if(!empty($resultPassing)){
            array_push($test, $resultPassing);
        }
    }
    print_r(json_encode($test));die;
}
public function passing($customer, $project){
    $date = DATE("Y-m-d");
    $time = DATE("H:i:s");
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT t_closed_by As Username, ixt_user_type.user_owner As Role,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 day THEN 1 END ) as today,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 7 day THEN 1 END ) as weekly,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 month THEN 1 END ) as monthly,
                  COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 year THEN 1 END ) as yearly
                FROM p_".$customer."_".$project."_ticket
                LEFT JOIN m_event_type ON p_".$customer."_".$project."_ticket.t_req_type = m_event_type.ev_type
                LEFT JOIN ixt_user_type ON m_event_type.ev_user_type_target = ixt_user_type.user_type
                WHERE t_status = 9
                GROUP BY t_closed_by; ");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: It still not work man, the format json array not like my expectation. I mean, my expectation just like this [[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"},{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}]]

Comment: your solution give the value [[{..}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}]],[[{..}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}]],[[{..}],[{..}],[{..}],[{..}]]

Comment: @aldi, I updated a line can you test it in your end it will display array, please see the output and change the code in if(!empty($resultPassing)) line, your code needs to be tuned according to your output

Answer (score 0):

Decode your json to an array of arrays.

Use `array_filter()` to remove the nulls.

Use `array_values()` to reindex the result.

Finally re-encode to json.

https://3v4l.org/fgKSd

```
$array = json_decode('[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"},{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}]]', true);
echo json_encode(array_values(array_filter($array)));
```

Output:

```
[[{"Username":"arnab@tmail.com","Role":"Software Engineer","today":"139","weekly":"391","monthly":"1149","yearly":"1149"},{"Username":"dolly@fmail.com","Role":"DevOps","today":"251","weekly":"405","monthly":"736","yearly":"736"}]]
```

The above use of `array_filter()` then `array_values()` eliminates the empty subarrays then assigns new indexes to the output array (`reset()` doesn't do what you need).

An optimal solution would be to redesign your sql query to eliminate the empty results from the query(from the earliest point). I have a feeling that replacing the LEFT JOINs with INNER JOINs will fix the issue.  Also, you should use table aliases in your query to to avoid rewriting the variable table name and generally improve code brevity/ readability.  As a matter of best practice, use ALL CAPS when writing mysql keywords.

```
public function passing($customer, $project) {
return $this->db->query(
    "SELECT t_closed_by AS Username,
            iutypes.user_owner AS Role,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN t_closed_time > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 1 END) AS today,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN t_closed_time > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 1 END) AS weekly,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN t_closed_time > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 1 END) AS monthly,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN t_closed_time > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR THEN 1 END) AS yearly
    FROM p_".$customer."_".$project."_ticket AS tickets
    INNER JOIN m_event_type AS metypes ON tickets.t_req_type = metypes.ev_type
    INNER JOIN ixt_user_type AS iutypes ON metypes.ev_user_type_target = iutypes.user_type
    WHERE t_status = 9
    GROUP BY t_closed_by"
    )->result_array();
}
```

If for some strange reason INNER JOIN isn't the fix, then you can using a HAVING clause to filter out rows that have a NULL value in just one of the columns.

FYI: Pushing into `$test` can be done without a function call like this:

```
$test[] = $this->passing($value['Customer'], $value['Project']);
```

Comment: @aldi have you seen my advice?